# JSession is giving me a blank page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

in a module that we want to display as a demo, i wanted to show what a login can look like
so no big need in security mesures.

my problem is the following : when i enter this code, the page goes blank. the frame doesn't load and looks like joomla don't get i'm loading a page. (no html)

it is my first time playing with JSession.

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Direct Access to this location is not allowed.' );
define("SHAKERCLASS"," jhShake_module");
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

$document   = &JFactory::getDocument();
$db         = &JFactory::getDBO();
$session    = JFactory::getSession();
$loginInfos = array(); 
if(!empty($session->get('login'))){
    $loginInfos = $session->get('login');
}else{
    $loginInfos = array("status" => "login", "username" => "", "password" => "");

    $session->set('login', $loginInfos);
}

$menuLogin  = "<div id='connexion'>
                <form name='input' action='$urlHere' method='POST'>
                    Username : <input type='text' name='usrn_Diffusion' />
                    Password : <input type='password' name='pass_Diffusion' />
                    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
                </form>
               </div>";


#DEMO LINE
$passwordOnOff = true;
if($passwordOnOff){

    if(!empty(JRequest::getVar('pass_Diffusion')) && !empty(JRequest::getVar('usrn_Diffusion'))){
            $loginInfos["status"]           = "logged";
            $loginInfos["password"]     = JRequest::getVar('pass_Diffusion');
            $loginInfos["username"]     = JRequest::getVar('usrn_Diffusion');

            $loginInfos = $session->set($loginInfos);
    }
    if($loginInfos["status"] == "logged"){
        if($password == $loginInfos["password"] && $username == $loginInfos["username"]){

        }else{
            $loginInfos["status"]           = "loginError";
            $loginInfos["password"]     = "";
            $loginInfos["username"]     = "";

            $loginInfos = $session->set($loginInfos);
        }
    }else{
        $output = $menuLogin;
        exit();
    }

}
```

EDIT :

The error line seems to be this one :

```
if(!empty($session->get('login'))){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can't use "empty" on the $session->get('login')

here's the correct way to do this :

```
if($session->get('login', false)){
```